# What is the difference between "can not" and "cannot"?

Tags: grammaticality

I have found both in texts of native English speakers but couldn't find the difference. In EL&U site people edited all my "can not" to *cannot*. So again I couldn't find out the matter.

Which of them is correct English and is there any possible difference to use them in different situations?

Comment: There is no good reason for preferring one over the other. Many people have bad reasons, including me: my wholly irrational practise is to discriminate by stress pattern (*cannot* is a trochee, **¯ ˘**, *can not* is a spondee **¯ ¯**) and use whichever sounds right in context.

Comment: How can I find which of them sounds right in a text as a non English speaker?

Comment: The point is, it doesn't matter. No reader will know why you did it, so it is quite literally meaningless.

Comment: @StoneyB- I do the same thing. Although I never analyzed it to that degree. And then, of course, there's *can't*

Comment: Look at this: http://ask.metafilter.com/6441/Cannot-vs-Can-Not. Everybody is trying to give a different answer!

Comment: Exactly! The rule is: write it any way you want; and when your editor changes, it's OK, because she cares and you don't.

Comment: Could you link to a specific example? I am pretty sure that "can not" is simply grammatically incorrect. DO: "cannot"
DON'T: "can not"

Comment: @Heisenberg: How can an orthographic variant be grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both forms have been in use since at least the 15th century, and both forms are acceptable today, although it appears* that *cannot* is far more common. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cannot) offers this comment:

> Both the one-word form **cannot** and the two-word form **can not** are acceptable, but **cannot** is more common (in the Oxford English Corpus, three times as common). The two-word form is better only in a construction in which **not** is part of a set phrase, such as ‘not only ... but (also)’: *Paul can not only sing well, he also paints brilliantly.*

I see no good reason for preferring one over the other. If you search the internet you will find that many people have *bad* reasons, some of them quite funny. Oxford's rule of thumb seems as reasonable as any, and more reasonable than most.

For what it's worth, my own wholly irrational practise is to discriminate by stress pattern (with *cannot* as a trochee ¯ ˘ and *can not* as a spondee ¯ ¯) and use whichever provides the reading my context demands.

---

* I have been unable to confirm this in corpora readily available to me. Google Ngrams refuses to distinguish the terms; and as reported from the BYU interface at http://corpus.byu.edu/, COCA prefers *can not* by more than 1,000 to 1, which cannot (or can not) be credited, while BNC does not acknowledge the existence of *cannot* at all.

Comment: I just saw this in M. Swan's grammar book (PEU 121.1.h): _Cannot_ is usually written as one word in British English. I also have an experience of being corrected from _can not_ to _cannot_ in this site, and have been wondering why.